# What is the Stencyl and StencylWorks business model?

Tags: business-model

Not sure how many of you have heard of [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/) as a low-barrier-to-entry game development platform, but for those of you that have worked with it - what is their business model? Nothing is free (unless it is open source and this is not), so what's the catch? How do they make their revenue?

EDIT: I *have* emailed them and have not heard back. Will certainly update when/if I do, though they will probably point me to the blog post that @thedaian found.

Got a response from Jonathan Chung @ Stencyl:

> We're starting off with the tried and true model of selling
>   subscriptions to export games to mobile platforms and HTML5. That will
>   be our bread and butter for a while.
>
> We expect though, that we'll end up making more off of other revenue
>   streams, such as running a carefully curated marketplace and other
>   kinds of online services in which we share revenue with users.

Comment: But why do you care?

Comment: Because why invest any time at all with a solution until you know exactly what you're getting into?

Comment: -1.  Have you asked them?

Comment: @Trevor. I have, actually. Maybe I should have mentioned it in the post - I'll update it. And haven't heard a response. You seem a little eager on the downvote.

Comment: @Tom I downvote questions which have the whiff of astroturf about them, and I downvote fact-based questions which show no signs of basic research, and I downvote questions which ask random internet strangers for a company's confidential internal business plans, as if those were common public knowledge.  Lots of apologies if my "-1. Have you asked them?" downvote comment didn't imply all of the above.  In future, I'll be more explicit about my reasons for downvotes.

Comment: @Trevor. Thanks for clarifying. Angry much?

Comment: @Tom It's not a matter of being angry.  It's a matter of downvoting a bad question, and then providing an explanation so that you could learn to ask better questions next time.  Again, apologies if I gave the impression that I was in any way upset with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have a [Roadmap](http://www.stencyl.com/stencylworks/roadmap/) on their site with a list of what their plans are. However, people that have worked with the engine wouldn't know the business plan is anymore than the average Facebook user would know what the business plan is/was.  It's unlikely that a random person making a game is going to know what the business plan of a new company is (unless it's obvious, like selling the software)

That said, if I had to guess, it's likely that they will charge something for the iOS and android versions, and the "Stencyl Market" could easily be another source of revenue.  If 10% of everything sold on the market goes to them, then hey, they've got a source of income.

Edit: Turns out they have a very obvious business model.  Lite and Pro versions, as described by [this blog post](http://blog.stencyl.com/?p=536).  It seems like publishing anywhere will require the Pro version, which is $149/year.

Comment: +1 That's some decent speculation. Anyone else have any confirmed facts?

Comment: @TomAuger I've edited my answer to include more information.  It seems like they *are* going to charge for a pro version of Stencyl.

Comment: Brilliant. That blog post clinches it.